# Issues with Render Selected in 2.8 (Ctrl-B)

Tags: rendering, selection-tools

Has anyone else had issues in 2.8 using the "render selected" tool that can be accessed by Ctrl-B in object mode? The selection box still shows up but it does not make a difference to what my viewport looks like

Comment: Admittedly I don't have an up-to-date version of 2.8, but isn't it called 'Render Region' (previously Render Border) and not 'Render Selected'?